# How to select groups of numbers with the same sum from an array

Tags: c++, c

I have an array from ten (or more) numbers, for example:

```
arr[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I want a method to check if three numbers from this arrays have the same sum to another three numbers (I want to get all the possibilities!), for example:

```
{1.8.10}  {2.10.7}  {3.7.9}   {4.9.6}   {5.6.8}  {Sum of each set: 19}
{1.6.10}  {3.10.4}  {5.4.8}   {7.8.2}   {9.2.6}  {Sum of each set: 17}
{6.3.5}   {7.5.2}   {8.2.4}   {9.4.1}   {10.1.3} {Sum of each set: 14}
```

#### Update:

That's another example to what exactly I want to do:

[alt text http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/1131/77603708.png](http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/1131/77603708.png)

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Where is this details girl? I was promised 'Her'

Comment: You need to be consistent in your syntax when you want to give examples. I'm assuming the `sum` and the `arr` of 10 integers (or more) is the **input**, and the **output** is all possible combinations of three elements from the array `arr` that satisfy the `sum`, right?

Comment: worse than homework, it's "project-euler"... it is supposed you solve those puzzles by yourself, or they make no sense, and moreover spoiling a result is bad practice!

Comment: But I tried more than 10 times ! That's doesn't make sense !

Comment: @the-ifl: If your approach to this problem is to select random triples of numbers and calculate their sum, you are not on the right track. A simpler solution exists, it's not that difficult to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a map of sets.  Setup a triple nested for loop and start adding numbers.  Every sum becomes a key into the map.  The set is the 3 numbers you used.  Should only be a dozen or so lines of code.

```
map<int,set<int> > sums;

for(int i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
{
  for(int j=0; j<ARRAY_SIZE; j++)
  {
    if(j <= i)
      continue;

    for(int k=0; k<ARRAY_SIZE; k++)
    {
      if(k <= i || k <= j)
        continue;

      int localSum = arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k];
      set<int> thisSum;
      thisSum.insert(arr[i]);
      thisSum.insert(arr[j]);
      thisSum.insert(arr[k]);
      sums.insert(make_pair(localSum, thisSum));
    }
  }
}
```

and just iterate through the sums map and display your sets as you want.  I'm not 100% sure on my continue logic here, but I think it's correct.  The idea will work, though it's at least cubic in complexity.

Comment: Can you give me all the project with an example  please ?

Comment: No.  That's not what this forum is about.  We answer questions and add code where needed to show answers, but I'm not giving you an entire solution.  I've given you 90% of what you need to solve your question.  The rest is a little debugging and some trivial output.  If you cannot do this yourself, then you have larger problems.

Comment: @the-ifl: Why are you asking for the entire answer to a Project Euler question? You won't get anything out of it if you just copy others' work...  @Michael Dorgan: Be careful about providing even this much code for Project Euler questions! Spoilers are bad.

Comment: I didn't even know what that was until well after I had answered the question and it was a bit late to take down the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

```
map<int,set<int> > sums;
for(int i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
{
  for(int j=0; j<ARRAY_SIZE; j++)
  {
    if(j <= i)
      continue;

    for(int k=0; k<ARRAY_SIZE; k++)
    {
      if(k <= i || k <= j)
        continue;

      int localSum = arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k];
      set<int> thisSum;
      thisSum.insert(arr[i]);
      thisSum.insert(arr[j]);
      thisSum.insert(arr[k]);
      sums.insert(make_pair(localSum, thisSum));
    }
  }
}
```